# android: how to validate a View object still in memory?

Tags: android

I am using a custom thread to fetch image from URL into an ImageView, I did this:

```
public class FetchThumbThread implements Runnable {
    ImageView gImage;
    String gUri;
    public FetchThumbThread(Object imageView, String uri) {
        // store parameter for later user
        gImage = (ImageView)imageView;
        gUri = uri;
    }

    public void run() {
        // fetch the image and store it in buffer.
        new runnable to be running in UIThread () {
            if (gImage still in memory) {
                 updating gImage;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Passing the imageview as the parameter, and update it in run()(will update in UIThread()).

But in case the ImageView has been destroyed(user press refresh button), I need to validate if the gImage pointer has gone... otherwise the program will crash.

How to do it in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically what you would do is have your Activity null out gImage inside of your runnable when it is no longer valid. Then, when you go to do work on the UI thread to update gImage, just check to make sure the imageView is not null.